# At which time exactly starts the ex-dividend-date?

Tags: dividends, ex-dividend-date

Let's say some US company declares the ex-divided-date as **Sep 30, 2020.** Now at which time exactly does this ex-date start? When this stock is traded in stock exchanges world wide, is the UTC time taken?

So **UTC Sep 30. 2020 00:00:01 AM** is the **first second** of the ex-date?

Comment: Worldwide? There are a lot of different exchanges in the world that have their own trading hours...

Answer (score 2):

Individual stocks aren’t traded 24/7, and they aren’t traded worldwide. A stock goes ex-dividend overnight, and starts to trade ex-dividend when the exchange on which it is traded opens in the morning.

Comment: No, the ex-dividend date is a date, not a time. Apple trades ex-dividend when the exchanges on which it is traded open on the ex-dividend date.